# Multistage amplifier design steps/process

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, audio, bjt, design

I have a project for one of my classes and it is to design a BJT multistage amplifier. I can use any combination of NPN or PNP and any type bias that I choose, but I do have a few constraints which are given by the professor which are to use a set input voltage, audio frequency, and power output.

I know how to perform the DC/AC analysis, gain, etcetera of a circuit that is already constructed, but I am unsure about how to design a circuit myself to give me the desired output freqency to power the 8 Ω speaker for the project.

I am looking for guidance on the proper steps of design such as (first do/calculate X), (second do/calculate Y), (third do/calculate Z) and so on. I will post the guidelines for the circuit just in case anyone is interested, but I DO NOT want anyone to work the circuit out for me, I'm just looking for guidance on how to do it myself.

Audio Amplifier Power Output selection: 3.2 W, 5.6 W, 7.1 W, 8.4 W, 11.5 W, and 16.3 W

Audio Amplifier Input Voltage (peak) selection: 150 mVpeak, 200 mVpeak, and 250 mVpeak

Audio Frequency: 20 Hz – 20 KHz

Comment: You can never do it yourself until to read how others do it and understand the methods used for current control, voltage control, power control, feedback and stability.   Learning how to learn is your goal, not the free guidance here.  Normally you are expected to learn Class A then Class A-B by splitting the wave in half and use separate channels for each polarity and merge with careful overlap bias control in Class A-B to prevent crossover distortion.

Comment: Are you only required to select ONE of the power output options you show? If so, pick the 3.2 W selection. It will be easier. Similarly, pick the 250 mW peak input selection. Your circuit will add less noise and be slightly easier, overall. Why make yourself work hard? (Unless you need to get some extra points.) For frequency, I'd say just select something like 1 kHz or 2 kHz. Easy to hear, speakers work pretty well with it, and there's no sense having to worry about 20 kHz issues if you don't need to.

Answer (score 1):

What you are really asking is how to design a circuit to certain specs.  There is no single answer or method to that, and I don't really know how to teach it.  But, this ability is what makes the difference between a really good EE, and one that merely cranks thru numbers.

The first requirement is that you must have some intuitive understanding of what the various building blocks at your disposal do.  Then you *creatively think* of ways of connecting them together to achieve your goal.  You do this a lot with simple circuits, wonder why they don't work as expected, have the "aha" moment, fix it, try the next thing, repeat many times.

If you start doing this by 7th grade or so at the latest, you'll have some intuition by college when the professor assigns you to design a audio power amp.  That's one of the things you inevitably tried, and failed a few times, to design on your own.  By now, you've probably got a small working audio amp you've designed yourself.

Eventually you'll have run across common sub-circuits that perform functions that seem to come up often inside larger circuits.  These include emitter followers, common emitter amplifiers, push-pull output stages, etc.  You will have played with different ways of biasing single transistor stages.  You have analyzed other circuits and seen how experienced EEs have solved particular problems.  Some impressed you as *"Hey, that's a cool idea"*, and you saved that idea away in your own brain.  Now it's your own cool way of addressing that particular problem.  Even better, you generalize the concept and use it in new ways when appropriate.

Those are all parts of real design.  That's a creative process, as apposed to rote cranking thru numbers to see what the currents and voltages are in a existing circuit.

However, none of the above tells you how to dig in and actually design the circuit.  As I said, I don't know how to teach that other then tell you to go back to 7th grade and start tinkering.

Since your early experiments you've learned a lot more about the theory, so now you understand why your previous attempts made noises on their own, blew up transistors, sounded really crappy, etc.  You've also been taught the eye-opening math of negative feedback, and actually understand things like power dissipation, how to calculate currents and voltages in a transistor circuit, and the like.  Now you're itching to design a better amp with all the new things you've learned.  You've even been assigned that as homework, so you can't wait to get started.  You'll show them the best amp a student ever came up with.  It doesn't get any better than this!

If at this point, several years into college, you have no idea where to start, you are on the wrong career path.  You will be able to brute-force or copy your way thru some problems, but it's too late for you to ever be really good at it.  Switch to marketing or run for elected office or something.

Comment: Does the professor assume that this student has already been taught the basics of transistors or did this student miss taking that college course?

Answer (score 0):

You have to start with the purpose of your circuit, whether it is a final amp or a power amp. Whether it is to have current or voltage gain, ..

You will then decide on a topology  . Like if it is a CFB or a vfb amp, class a or class b....

You then figure the idle parameters for the stages.

From that you nail down individual parameters, output devices, heat sinks, .....

Not possible to discuss in general terms.

Answer (score 0):

Step#1: perform a ClassA design, taking 0.25volt up to sufficient voltage swing to provide 3.2 watts into on 8_ohm resistive load, using capacitive coupling from the final transistor's collector to the 8_ohm load. Can you do this with just one stage? What is that stage is a Darlington? With a constant-current load, operating at 5 amperes and 20 volts (with 40 volt rail); I'm assuming 20 volts Peak swing will provide 3.2 watts into 8_ohm load.

Given a stage gain is GM*Rload, and a 5 ampere Icollector produces Gm of 5/0.026 = 200 amps/volt, a simple Darlington is a fine starting point.

(edit) However, 5 amps and 40 volts is 200 watts quiescent, to produce only 3.2 watts into the speaker. Thus people consider classB, or AB, where idling current of 0.1 amp at 40 volts is only 4 watts. Then you have cross-over distortion, where the output signal includes music-program-zero-crossing transients that are correlated to the music BUT NOT HARMONIC ENERGY and our ears really really do not like non-harmonic energy. Of course, Distortion Analyzers coerce non-fundamental energy into either (1) harmonics or (2) noise, thus the zero-crossing trash gets poked into the "noise" class, when the real problem is the correlation between music and ZC---e.g. ZC ain't "noise".

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but no it cannot be done in just one stage it has to be a minimum of two stages and cant use a darlington or an op amp only bjt.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a current-source load, to achieve high gain in just one stage? The maximum gain you can get with one stage, using a resistive load, is VDD/0.026. Thus 26 volts, with very careful biasing, allows gain of 1,000. You only need a gain of 10 or 20 or 30. So resistive loads, on a CE topology, makes a good first stage.